# Access data from outside a for loop

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop

I'm iterating over JSON data and taking the data and assigning it to a global variable, when I print the variable within the loop I get all the data, however, when I print the variable outside the loop I'm only getting the last pieces of data from the JSON object. My objective is to take the data and pass it as a parameter of a function. How do I get all the data outside the loop?

```
var stockParam = [String]()
for info in stockInfo {
   self.stockParam = [info.symbol]
   print("inside \(stockParam)")
 }
             
  print("outside \(stockParam)")
fetchProfileData(stock: stockParam)
```

Comment: Please do some basic research on how to use an array, it should be `self.stockParam.append(info.symbol)`. The Swift Programming Language book is a good place to start when you want to learn more about swift, [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID107) is a section about Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you are setting stockParam as array of one element (info.symbol):

```
self.stockParam = [info.symbol]
```

---

To hold all info symbols in stockParam array you have to append element on every iteration:

```
for info in stockInfo {
    self.stockParam.append(info.symbol)
 }
```

Or simply use map function:

```
var stockParam = stockInfo.map {$0.symbol}
```